# simplest way to query Solr for an absolute value

Tags: function, rest, solr

I know similar questions have been asked WRT function querying, but I'd like to simply query Solr for a field with absolute value greater than or equal to something. for example, field change can be a negative or positive integer. I'd like to query (REST) along the lines of abs(change):[2 TO *]. How would I accomplish this/is it possible?

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Function Range Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-FunctionRangeQueryParser) can be used for this:

```
{!frange l=2}abs(change)
```

There is also a possibility to include(default)/exclude lower and upper bounds if needed.
More details available in [Solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-FunctionRangeQueryParser).

---

## Update

In case there is a need to combine the function query with a regular one, the [magic _val_](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Usingthe'magicfields'_val_and_query_) field name can be used:

```
field1:("xxxx") AND _val_:"{!frange l=2}abs(change)"
```

Comment: that's a start, but (a) the wiki is short on practical examples for me and I was unable to get it to work based on the documentation I could find. Your example really helped.

I need to combine this with and AND clause, as in field1:("xxxx") AND {!frange l=2}abs(change) any idea how to accomplish that?